# Typescript: Can a class method be a decorator of another method?

Tags: typescript

Could something like the following work?

```
class A {
  private mySecretNumber = 2;

  decorate (f: (x :number) => number) {
    return (x: number) => f(this.mySecretNumber * x);
  }

  @(this.decorate)
  method (x: number) {
    return x + 1;
  }
}
```

I tried with `@this['decorate'],` `@A['decorate']`, `@A.decorate`, can't find anything.

Here's an example of my use case: https://kutt.it/uOxVgM. Ideally I would just decorate `getAbc()` and `get123()`.

Comment: Can you explain your use case more specifically? It looks like you're trying to preserve encapsulation by defining the decorator inside the class but, in actuality, your private member is not private and there are easier solutions that would allow it to be private

Comment: @AluanHaddad Added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many subtleties to your question.

The first thing is, yes, you can indeed use a method as a decorator, but not by writing `@this.decorate` (during transpiling, `this` would be the `globalThis` instead of `A`) or `@A.decorate` (`decorate` is not a static method, so `A.decorate` does not exist). The correct answer to this part of the question is `@A.prototype.decorate`; this will locate exactly what you have in mind.

The second thing is, when applying a decorator to a method of a class, the argument of the decorator is not the method function itself, but it actually have 3 arguments: a target object (which would be `A.prototype` in our case), a string (the name of the method, which is `"method"` in our case), and a property descriptor object. It also does not return a new function, but it should return a new property descriptor if not void. So inside the decorator function, you should try to modify the target object instead of trying to return a new function.

Putting things together, a working example will be:

```
class A {
    private mySecretNumber = 2;

    decorate(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        var f = descriptor.value;
        // Don't use arrow function here, otherwise "this"
        // will not be the current A instance.
        descriptor.value = function(x: number) {
            return f(this.mySecretNumber * x);
        };
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
    }

    @A.prototype.decorate
    method(x: number) {
        return x + 1;
    }
}

var a = new A();
console.log(a.method(3)); // 7
```

### Update:

Based on your use case, I will use the following approach. Basically you use a static decorator to load the abstract `decorate` method, which can be implemented in subclasses. I modify the example above to give you an idea how it can be done.

```
abstract class A {
    protected abstract decorate(x: number): number;

    static decorate(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        var f = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function(x: number) {
            return f(this.decorate(x));
        };
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
    }

    @A.decorate
    method(x: number) {
        return x + 1;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private mySecretNumber = 2;
    protected decorate(x: number) { return this.mySecretNumber * x; }
}

var b = new B();
console.log(b.method(3)); // 7
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer is favor of yours, because creating an instance of the class (the approach that I suggested) expresses that the decorator would have access to the `this` instance, which it turns out not to have. It seems like the the best be for a "method decorator" is for it to  be static, given that it will lack access to the `this`.

Comment: Yes, I would use a static decorator myself as well. To be honest, a non-static decorator makes little sense in general, but it's still interesting to figure out that it can be done.

Comment: My use case is I have an abstract class, where `decorate()` is abstract, and `method()` is fully defined as in the example. In my concrete classes, I only need to implement `decorate()`. But in TS you can't have abstract static methods, any ideas on alternative "cleaner" ways to achieve that?

Comment: OK, so in your abstract class there's a concrete `method()`, and you want to decorate it in the subclass, by different ways for each subclasses? I don't think the structure you describe can achieve what you want, because the decoration will not automatically apply to the subclasses simply by implementing the `decorate()` method; you still need to write down the decoration above the `method()` inside your subclasses, so you're not really re-using any code, and thus you don't really need a `decorate()` in the abstract class.

Comment: I believe that you don't really need to use decoration at all, you should just override `method()` in the subclasses (and call `super.method()` in the new function when needed).

Comment: Here's my use case: https://kutt.it/uOxVgM. What you suggest is that I need to rewrite `get123()`, `getAbc()` for each subclass? Imo that's not really scalable.

Comment: @amaurymartiny I've updated my answer; see if that works for you.

Comment: why use prototype in your first answer? will you give a more detailed introduction?

Comment: @高欣平 Um, I'm not very good in explaining it, but basically the prototype object is where the instance method function is actually defined and to be found.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that this refers to the Legacy decorator implementation provided by TypeScript and older versions of Babel.**

You could do this by implementing a decorator with a type constraint that limits its applicability to classes that implement the `mySecretNumber` property. This would fix both the syntax and the semantics of the scoping problems that Mu-Tsun Tsai [explained so well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56716378/1915893).

Here is what I would prefer:

```
class A {
    mySecretNumber = 2;
    @decorate
    method(x: number) {
        return x + 1;
    }
}

function decorate<T extends { mySecretNumber: number }, K extends keyof T>(
    target: T, key: K,
    descriptor: T[K] extends (n: number) => number ? TypedPropertyDescriptor<(n: number) => number> : never
) {
    const f = descriptor.value;
    if (f) {
        descriptor.value = function (this: T, x: number) {
            return f(this.mySecretNumber * x);
        };
    }
    return descriptor;
}
```

This ensures that the decorated class has a `mySecretNumber` property of type `number`, binds that member to the desired `this`, and as a bonus ensures that the decorated method has the correct signature.

Comment: There is a downside in using the generic decorator though: TypeScript will only allow you to decorate public members of a class (to me that is weird, but currently that's the rule). In your example if you set `method()` to be protected then an error will occur.

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai that's true  but I don't see it as a downside because visibility modifiers are vacuous in TypeScript and will be superseded by a future version of ECMAScript that provides truly private members. If you want encapsulation, you need closures and it's always been that way in JavaScript and continues to be in TypeScript